# ¿Cómo filtro un campo concreto de un CSV con Grep?

Tags: regex, bash, grep, procesamiento-de-texto

Tengo el siguiente archivo .csv:

```
name, id, nametype, class, mass, fall, year, reclat,reclon, geolocation
Gari Yasin,10,Valid,L5,101,Fell,01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM,50.775000,6.083330,"(50.775; 6.083330)"
Attenea,Valid,L5,21,Fell,01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM,50.775000,6.083330,"(50.775; 6.083330)"
Galim (b),10849,Valid,EH3/4-an,22,Fell,01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM,50.775000,6.083330,"(50.775; 6.083330)"
Atemajac,10849,Valid,EH3/4-an,94.2,Fell,01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM,50.775000,6.083330,"(50.775; 6.083330)"
```

Quiero encontrar esos registros donde "mass" (el 5.º campo) sea inferior a 100 usando regex. No puedo filtrar columnas ni usar `awk`. Solamente puedo usar el comando `grep`.

He hecho lo siguiente:

```
grep -E ",[0-9][0-9],"
```

Sin embargo,  el campo id para el meteorito con nombre Gari Yasin también cumple la condición pero su masa no y me devuelve el registro. Además, el registro con nombre Atemajac tiene la masa con un valor decimal (float) con valor 94.2, pero tampoco obtengo el resultado ¿Cómo puedo acceder únicamente al campo `mass`y obtener los registros con números decimales?

La salida debería ser:

```
Attenea,Valid,L5,21,Fell,01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM,50.775000,6.083330,"(50.775; 6.083330)"
Galim (b),10849,Valid,EH3/4-an,22,Fell,01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM,50.775000,6.083330,"(50.775; 6.083330)"
Atemajac,10849,Valid,EH3/4-an,94.2,Fell,01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM,50.775000,6.083330,"(50.775; 6.083330)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que indicar de alguna forma que se trata del 5.º campo:

```sh
grep -E '^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[0-9]{1,2},' fichero
#         ^^^^^ ^^^^^ ^^^^^ ^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^
#          1.º   2.º   3.º   4.º   este es el
#                                 que filtras
```

Como ves, indicando `[^,]*,` vas *recogiendo* campo a campo hasta llegar al que quieres filtrar. Y allí es donde pones el filtro `[0-9]{1,2}` para indicar que sea un número natural inferior a 100.

Si también quieres incluir números decimales, puedes usar `[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]+)?,`, es decir, añadir `(\.[0-9]+)?` de modo que la parte decimal sea opcional. Todo entero queda en:

```
grep -E '^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]+)?,' fichero
```

Comment: Como podria indicarle que se acepten los numeros decimales inferiores a cien también? Ahora mismos, con la instrucción solo coge números enteros.

Comment: @Panri93 deberías actualizar tu pregunta dando ejemplos. Por ejemplo, de si el número tiene un punto o una coma para separar decimales, etc.

Comment: hecho. He añadido el ejemplo que pediste.

Comment: @Panri93 vale, mira mi actualización

Comment: Gracias! Me había dejado el ? y por eso no me salía...